# Database file at path [laravel] does not exist. Ensure this is an absolute path to the database

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, docker

Database file at path [laravel] does not exist. Ensure this is an absolute path to the database.

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// Determine if the application is in maintenance mode...

if (file_exists($maintenance = **DIR**.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {

```
require $maintenance;
```

}

// Register the Composer autoloader...

require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Bootstrap Laravel and handle the request...

(require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php')

```
->handleRequest(Request::capture());
```